# Required a Project with Struts2 and Hibernate3(Using .hbm file) implemented

Tags: java, struts2, hibernate3

Can anyone please point me at a small project which has a good implementation on Struts 2 and Hibernate 3 (.hbm file not with annotations)?

Comment: a simple Google search came up with this. http://www.google.co.in/search?q=strts2+%2Bhibernate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-tutorial/struts-2-tutorial.html

As far as I know, the site above is the best site for beginners who are starting projects in Struts2. It has a tutorial for Struts + Hibernate integration. Also you can download sample sources.

Comment: This site is really useful..Thanks a lot